# MySQL - get latest record when date and time are two fields

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, deadlock

I have a DB in which date and time are two columns. I need to get the latest (by latest I mean the record with the highest time) row. This is used as a sub query to feed another query.

DB

```
id      date       time    currentOdometer    totalOdometer       vno
 1   2020-03-21    10:00      250                  3001          ABCD
 2   2020-03-21    09:59      249                  3000          ABCD          
 3   2020-03-21    10:01      251                  3002          ABCD
 4   2020-03-21    10:02      252                  3003          ABCD
```

My requirement is that when I get a new record of vno ABCD, i need to find the latest record and manipulate the data.

For instance, when i get a new record at 10:03, i need to find the latest record, ie 10:02 and the value.

My query was

```
(
SELECT Y.currentOdometer+(3200-Y.totalOdometer) 
FROM tbl Y 
WHERE timeStamp(date,time) = 
(
  SELECT MAX(timeStamp(X.date,X.time)) 
  FROM tbl X WHERE vno= 'ABCD') AND vno= 'ABCD'
)
```

This query is part of an INSERT statement like this

```
INSERT INTO tbl(date, time, currentOdometer, totalOdometer, vno) 
VALUES ('2020-03-21', '10:03',(SELECT Y.currentOdometer+(3200-Y.totalOdometer) 
FROM tbl Y 
WHERE timeStamp(date,time) = 
(
  SELECT MAX(timeStamp(X.date,X.time)) from tbl X 
  WHERE vno= 'ABCD') AND vno= 'ABCD'),3003,'ABCD'
)
```

When I run the query in this manner, i get the error the Subquery returns more than one row.

The i re framed the query with LIMIT 1 in each of the select statemtn and then there is a deadlock on the

```
ER_LOCK_DEADLOCK: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
ER_LOCK_DEADLOCK
undefined
```

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? Please always include it in your questions - edit the tags! Also, could you please provide your table structures as DDL and your data as DML. Help us to help you! p.s. as @Lennart says, do **not** use [SQL keywords](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/coding-standards/list-of-sql-reserved-words)!

Comment: Noted ... MySQL keywords have been changed to new names.

Comment: Could you please include **all** of the your query/(ies) - the field `IMEI` isn't there for example. The query as written can't run, so any solution that we may propose can't be tested!

Comment: The field is vno not IMEI. That was a typo error.

Comment: There are more fields to the table. My issue is that there is almost 50 to 80 times the query is being executed in a minute and the data being inserted to the db. I get the data to be inserted once or twice after which there is an DEADLOCK error. There are almost 25 fields

Comment: 1) In the `mysql` CLI, create a table with a small subset of  your records - `CREATE TABLE tmp AS SELECT * FROM gps_data WHERE x = y` (get about 5 - 7 records. Then issue the command `mysqldump -u username -p --single-transaction --quick --lock-tables=false db1 tmp > tmp.sql` and then post the results here - we need **as much information as possible** to be able to answer. Then, with those sample records, and the structures of the two tables (from and to) show us what data moves from where to where!

Answer (score 1):

For questions like this, CREATE TABLE statements together with INSERT statements for sample data is truly useful. Even better is a [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=06073f8adae8d59fb89c8a415d4b398f) or similar. Right now, all I can do is give you some ideas, but I won't be able to test it.

Looking at your query:

```
INSERT INTO tbl(date, time, currentOdometer, totalOdometer, vno) 
VALUES ('2020-03-21', '10:03',(SELECT Y.currentOdometer+(3200-Y.totalOdometer) 
FROM tbl Y 
WHERE timeStamp(date,time) = 
(
  SELECT MAX(timeStamp(X.date,X.time)) from tbl X 
  WHERE vno= 'ABCD') AND IMEI = 'ABCD'),3003,'ABCD'
)
```

There are probably some syntax errors ( un-balanced ")" for the sub-select, or at least they are in the wrong place ), but you should not use the VALUES clause together with a sub-select, better to re-write like:

```
INSERT INTO tbl(date, time, currentOdometer, totalOdometer, vno) 
SELECT '2020-03-21', '10:03', Y.currentOdometer+(3200-Y.totalOdometer) 
FROM tbl Y 
WHERE timeStamp(date,time) = 
(
  SELECT MAX(timeStamp(X.date,X.time)) from tbl X 
  WHERE vno= 'ABCD') AND IMEI = 'ABCD'),3003,'ABCD'
)
```

As a side-note, avoid using reserved words as identifiers (date, time, timestamp).

The WHERE clause also looks wrong, I assume 3003 and 'ABCD' are values for totalOdometer, vno. Is this what you mean?

```
INSERT INTO tbl(date, time, currentOdometer, totalOdometer, vno) 
SELECT '2020-03-21', '10:03', Y.currentOdometer+(3200-Y.totalOdometer) 
      , 3003, 'ABCD'
FROM tbl Y 
WHERE timeStamp(date,time) = (
  SELECT MAX(timeStamp(X.date,X.time)) 
  from tbl X 
  WHERE vno= 'ABCD' 
    AND IMEI = 'ABCD'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I've found for the similar project is a little denormalization of the database.

Along the table containing every point for all the vnos you have to create the auxiliary table of the same structure except there is no `ID` column and `vno` column is a primary key. On each insert into the main table you have to `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` into the auxiliary table where only the last received values are stored for each vno. Sure you have to verify is newly received date and time are bigger than existing ones. Some trackers can send NMEA in an arbitrary order in some cases.

This approach has a little overhead (two inserts instead of single one) but allows to avoid time-consuming grouping for MAX() calculations. Indeed it's better to wrap both inserts and validations into transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You have found a problem with splitting date and time.  But it is not unsolvable.

I discuss how to iterate through a compound key here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#iterating_through_a_compound_key

Instead of using `MAX`, use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT 1`.

If you are using MySQL 8 or MariaDB 10.2, there is also the `OVER` windowing function.